# NoClassDefFoundError despite using api for dependency in a library

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Android library foolib has the following in in its build.gradle:

```
api('com.github.hedzr:android-file-chooser:v1.2.0-final')
```

The library generates its aar file foolib.aar. App MyApp uses foolib.aar. foolib has many functions and all of them work fine except the file chooser. When MyApp uses a library function that uses the file chooser, it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/obsez/android/lib/filechooser/ChooserDialog
```

I thought `api` makes the dependency transitive and the MyApp would get the library. If I use the following in MyApp's build.grale, everything will be fine:

```
implementation 'com.github.hedzr:android-file-chooser:v1.2.0-final'
```

Could anyone shed some light on this? I am asking this to help me understand `api`.